# Required fields in php form not work properly

Tags: php, required-field

I would like to set all the fields of my form as "required". I know there are already similar questions with many good answers but unfortunately I could not find the problem with my code.

What I need is to show the error message ONLY if user has left some fields empty, but is if I answer all the questions in the form it shows  the error "Oops...all fields are required". Could someone please help me?

Here is what I tried:

```
 session_start();

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
   $_SESSION['q1'] = $_POST['q1'];
   $_SESSION['q2'] = $_POST['q2'];
   $_SESSION['q3'] = $_POST['q3'];
   $_SESSION['q4'] = implode(',', $_POST['birthplace']);
   $_SESSION['q5'] = implode(',', $_POST['countrylived']);

   $q1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['q1']);
   $q2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['q2']);
   $q3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['q3']);
   $q4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['q4']);
   $q5 = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['q5']);

   $required = array('q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4', 'q5');
   $error = false;
   foreach($required as $field) {
     if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
       $error = true;
     }
   }

   if ($error) {
      echo "Oooops!! It seems you did not answer all the questions. Please not that all fields are required.";
   } 
  else {

       $query="INSERT INTO test (q1, q2, q3, q4, q5) VALUES ('$q1', '$q2', '$q3', '" . $q4 . "', '" . $q5 . "')";
        mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error() );
        header('Location: Thankyou.php'); 
        exit;
     }
}
    ?>
```

EDIT: here is part of my html form. (sorry it contains many questions so I just chose the part related to q1-5)

```
<ul id="page_1">

<div class="meter"><span style="width: 20%">Step 1</span></div>

<fieldset id = "Form1"> <h3> <legend>Please answer the following questions carefully in order to help us providing you with the best recommendation</legend> </h3>

<fieldset id = "q1"> <legend class="Q1"></legend>
<span> What is your gender?</span>
<div class="fieldset content">
<p>
<Input type = 'radio' Name ='q1' value = 'male'>Male
<Input type = 'radio' Name ='q1' value = 'female'>Female
</p>
</div>
</fieldset>


<fieldset id = "q2"> <legend class="Q2"></legend>
<span>  What is your age?</span>
<div class="fieldset content">
<p>
<Input type = 'radio' Name = 'q2' value = 'under 18'>Under 18
<Input type = 'radio' Name = 'q2' value = '18-30'>18-30
<Input type = 'radio' Name = 'q2' value = '31-40'>31-40
<Input type = 'radio' Name = 'q2' value = '41-60'>41-60
<Input type = 'radio' Name = 'q2' value = 'over 60'>Over 60
</p>
</div>
</fieldset>


<fieldset id = "q3"> <legend class="Q3"></legend>
<span> 3. What is your marital status?</span> 
<div class="fieldset content">
<p>
<Input type = 'radio' Name = 'q3' value = 'married'>Married or domestic partnership
<Input type = 'radio' Name = 'q3' value = 'single'>Single
<Input type = 'radio' Name = 'q3' value = 'would rather not say'>Would rather not say
<p>
</div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id = "q4"> <legend class="Q4"></legend>
<span> 4. Where were you born?</span>
<div class="fieldset content">
<p>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "Mypass") or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db("imdb")or die("Connection Failed");
$query = "SELECT * FROM Country"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>

<select name="birthplace[]" multiple="multiple" width="200px" size="10px"> 

<?php while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
?>
<option value="<?php echo $line['country'];?>"> <?php echo $line['country'];?> 
 </option>  
 <?php 
 }  
 ?>
</select>  
</p>
</div>
</fieldset>


<fieldset id = "q5"> <legend class="Q5"></legend>
<span> 5. Please select the country/countries where you have lived there at least for 5 years?</span>
<div class="fieldset content">
// THE SAME PROCEDURE AS Q4 //

   ......
    .....
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button">
  </fieldset>
  </ul>

  </form>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: quick nasty fix: `if (empty($$field))` why? because you dont have `q4` or `q5` in your form

Comment: You are adding `q1` - `q5` to session, but checking `_POST` elements.

Comment: @user574632: sorry I didnt understand what u mean bye I don't have q4 or q5? I have them in the form..

Comment: @Justinas: If u mean what sherwoor suggested, I tested also with sessions but nothing changed :(

Comment: @mOna Unless you show the form, im just guessing. But as you dont use the variables $_POST['q4'] or $_POST['q5'] anywhere apart from this loop, it was a fair guess

Comment: After your edit, I still see comparison with `$_POST` and your `q4` and `q5` is only `$_SESSION` variables. And your database insertion is vulnerable to attacks

Comment: @Justinas: Thanks for your useful comments. I changed $_POST to $_SESSION[$field] and it works properly now. Just could you please explain me what is the problem with my DB insertion? thanks

Comment: @mOna read about Sql Injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that your code is checking variables that will always be empty: note that it looks like you don't have $_POST['q4'] or $_POST['q5'] in your form.

In your checker, try testing the session fields that you have assigned instead:

```
   $required = array('q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4', 'q5');
   $error = false;
   foreach($required as $field) {
     if (empty($_SESSION[$field])) {
       $error = true;
     }
   }
```

Alternatively, you might want to check what is in your birthplace and countrylived fields. If they aren't arrays then the implode function won't return anything.

If this doesn't work, add:

```
if(empty($_SESSION['q1'])) {
    echo "q1 is empty!";
}
if(empty($_SESSION['q2'])) {
    echo "q2 is empty!";
}
if(empty($_SESSION['q3'])) {
    echo "q3 is empty!";
}
if(empty($_SESSION['q4'])) {
    echo "q4 is empty!";
}
if(empty($_SESSION['q5'])) {
    echo "q5 is empty!";
}
```

To find out which fields are the problem.

Comment: I tried what you said, but still even if I fill all the answers I receive the error"ooppsss.. all fields required!" :(((

Comment: Can you post the form as well and I'll see what's going on

Comment: I have tested your form and it works fine for me.  See my answer above for a code snippet to try.  Try it and let me know what happens.

Comment: @sherwoor: I wrote your second check (check each field separately),I tested but for instance I didn't fill q2 and q4, but now the proble is the opposite! in any case it redirect me to thank you page after submit!

Comment: @sherwoor: It solved :) I really donno why it suddenly worked! I just tried with $SESSION[$field], at first it didnt work but now it works fine! Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

Most likely some fields are empty.
Check if all form fields have been filled by displaying it's content after you submit the form.

simply add `var_dump($_POST);exit;` at the top of your PHP code and post the results.

Comment: I did as you said and after submit it showed me this:  array(8) { ["q1"]=> string(4) "male" ["q2"]=> string(5) "18-30" ["birthplace"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "Angola" } ["p_scnt"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["d_scnt"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["e_scnt"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["priorities"]=> string(0) "" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" }